# PHP Ratchet - multiple clients

Tags: php, zeromq, ratchet

I am using PHP Ratchet (push integration) for my app with real time biddings and it works like a charm.

Due to high traffic we moved our app on AWS platform and we have a multiple app server instances and one of them (Ratchet).

```
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
```

This means than I can connect only from one app instance, but can I add here mutliple clients (my app instances on AWS)?
I need to connect from multiple localhosts machines due to load balancing.

Is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 which will allow all connections from any server as long as they can access port 5555 on that machine.

Comment: Yes I know for that, but what about security? I dont want to anyone pushes.

Comment: Use the security groups to restrict access to which servers can talk to the ratchet machine on port 5555.